# JQuery.When promises not resolving in recursive async call

Tags: jquery, recursion, jquery-deferred

**RESOLVED** See answer.

I have a recursive async call that is being resolved at the first call, but I would like to resolve it at the end of the recursivity (where I put 'return "1"'). Any help?

```
function parent(){
    asyncCall().then(function(result){
       console.log(result);
    });
}


function asyncCall(parameters){
    var promises = [];
    promises.push(
            anotherAsyncFunction(Parameters).then(function (returnedData) {
                if (returnedData==1) {
                    return "1"; //Should resolve here.
                } else {
                    parameters.modify(returnedData);
                    promises.push(asyncCall(parameters)); //Why resolves here??
                }

            })
        );
   return jQuery.when.apply(null, promises);
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Based on: [AngularJS, promise with recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607313/angularjs-promise-with-recursive-function)

I've resolved it changing from an array of promises to a deferred object passed all the way through. So now is working:

```
function asyncCall(parameters, deferred){
    if (!deferred) {
        deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    }

    anotherAsyncFunction(Parameters).then(function (returnedData) {
         if (returnedData==1) {
            return deferred.resolve("1"); 
         } else {
            parameters.modify(returnedData);
            asyncCall(parameters, deferred); //Passing deferred object
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```