# Recursive queries with promises in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I have a recursive query that needs to potentially make further queries based on the results. I would ideally like to be able to construct a promise chain so that I know when all of the queries are finally complete.

I've been using the [example from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607313/angularjs-promise-with-recursive-function), and I have the following method:

```
 this.pLoadEdges = function(id,deferred) {
    if (!deferred) {
        deferred = $q.defer();
    }
    $http.post('/Create/GetOutboundEdges', { id: id }).then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data;

        if (data.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var subID = data[i].EndNode;

                edgeArray.push(data[i]);

                self.pLoadEdges(subID, deferred);
            }
        } else {
            deferred.resolve();
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    });

    deferred.notify();
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Which I then start elsewhere using:

```
 self.pLoadEdges(nodeID).then(function() {
                    var edgedata = edgeArray;
                });
```

And of course I intend to do some more stuff with the edgeArray.

The problem is that the then() function is trigged whenever any individual path reaches an end, rather than when *all* the paths are done. One particular pathway might be quite shallow, another might be quite deep, I need to know when all of the pathways have been explored and they're all done.

How do I construct a promise array based on this recursive query, ideally so that I can use $q.all[] to know when they're all done, when the number of promises in the promise array depends on the results of the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive what the end result of the function should be, but it looks like it should be a flat array of edges based on the example that you provides.  If that's correct, then the following should work

```
this.pLoadEdges = function(id) {
    var edges = [];

    // Return the result of an IIFE so that we can re-use the function
    // in the function body for recursion
    return (function load(id) {
        return $http.post('/Create/GetOutboundEdges', { id: id }).then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;

            if (data.length > 0) {
                // Use `$q.all` here in order to wait for all of the child
                // nodes to have been traversed. The mapping function will return
                // a promise for each child node.
                return $q.all(data.map(function(node) {
                    edges.push(node);

                    // Recurse
                    return load(node.EndNode);
                });
            }
        });
    }(id)).then(function() {
        // Change the return value of the promise to be the aggregated collection
        // of edges that were generated
        return edges;
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
svc.pLoadEdges(someId).then(function(edgeArray) {
// Use edgeArray here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) function:

> Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.

---

#### Update 1

Check this demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rg1kk1e/)

The controller can be like following code (well, you may want to put it in a `factory`).

It loads a list of users first, then for each user, load the posts of this user. I use [`JSONPlaceholder`](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) to get the fake data.

`$q.all` accepts an array of promises and combine them into one promise. The message `All data is loaded` is only displayed after all data is loaded. Please check the console.

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$http', function ($scope, $q, $http) {
    function load() {
        return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data.data);
            var users = data.data;
            var userPromises = users.map(function (user) {
                return loadComment(user.id);
            });
            return $q.all(userPromises);
        });
    }

    function loadComment(userId) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + userId).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    load().then(function () {
        console.log('All data is loaded');
    });
}]);
```

---

#### Update 2

You need a recursive function, so, check: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rg1kk1e/4/).

The code is below. I use `round` to jump out of the recursion because of the fake API. The key is here: `$q.all(userPromises).then(function () { deferred.resolve(); });`. That tells: `Please resolve this defer object after all promises are resolved`.

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('JoyCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$http', function ($scope, $q, $http) {
    var round = 0;

    function load(userId) {
        return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + userId)
            .then(function (data) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            console.log(data.data);
            var posts = data.data;
            if (round++ > 0 || !posts || posts.length === 0) {
                deferred.resolve();
            } else {
                var userPromises = posts.map(function (post) {
                    return load(post.userId);
                });
                $q.all(userPromises).then(function () {
                    deferred.resolve();
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        });
    }

    load(1).then(function () {
        console.log('All data is loaded');
    });
}]);
```

Comment: I know, but how do I build up the promise array when the number of promises depends on the result of the query from the promise itself?

Comment: Why do you not just return an array of promises, from a minimum length of 1, then wrap them all together within a `.when` statement that operates over an array that is the concatenation of all the returned arrays? That's what I was getting at above.

Comment: But how do I even return the array of promises to start with? That's the part I don't understand. I have a query, which is 1 promise. That query may (or may not) return results that require more queries, more promises, which may in turn require more queries, and so on.

Comment: How would you do that if it's a recursive method? The response from load() calls loadComment() and then it stops, but what if load() has to call load() itself? What do you return?

Comment: @RamblerToning Please check the answer updated for recursive calling.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That was absolutely the key, adding deferred.resolve() within the $q.all .then call!

Comment: @RamblerToning My pleasure. You picked the answer from @dherman, could you please further verify that the solution works? Maybe we do not need the `$q.defer()` thing.

Comment: I tried them both and they both work. @dherman's code works just as is, and your answer works when I implement your suggestions into the previous code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try building up an array of returned promises and then use the `$.when.apply($, <array>)` pattern. I've used it before to accomplish a similar thing to what you're describing.

[More info on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777031/what-does-when-apply-somearray-do).

UPDATE:

You probably also want to read the docs on the [apply function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), it's pretty neat.